Custom numbering for `example` and `solution` environments in Beamer that resets with each example
I'm currently using the Beamer document class to create presentations and have defined two custom environments, example and solution, for my slides. However, the default numbering scheme is not what I desire. Here's the current numbering pattern I'm getting:
example 1
solution 2
example 3
solution 4
solution 5
example 6
solution 7

What I would like to achieve is a numbering scheme where each example is followed by one or more solution environments that reset their numbering with each new example. The desired numbering pattern is as follows:
example 1
solution 1
example 2
solution 1
solution 2
example 3
solution 1

I've attempted to customize these environments myself, but when I try to incorporate animations within the same frame, I encounter new issues that I'm unable to resolve.
Here's a simplified version of what I've tried so far:
\documentclass{beamer}

\newtheorem{theorems}{Theorem}[section]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

% ... (Custom commands for environments go here)

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{example}
        Example content here.
    \end{example}
    \begin{solution}
        Solution content here.
    \end{solution}
    \begin{example}
        Example content here.
    \end{example}
    \begin{solution}
        Solution content here.
    \end{solution}
    \begin{solution}
        Solution content here.
    \end{solution}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

When I try to use \only or \pause for animations, the counters do not behave as expected, and the numbering gets out of sync with the content being displayed.
Does anyone know how to correctly implement the numbering I'm looking for? And could you provide guidance on how to maintain the correct numbering while using Beamer's animation features?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Quick hack: define the solution theorem yourself to make sure that it does not share a counter with all other theorems
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\let\solution\undefined
\let\thesolution\undefined

\newtheorem{solution}{\translate{Solution}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{example}{\setcounter{solution}{0}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{example}
        Example content here.
    \end{example}
    \begin{solution}
        Solution content here.
    \end{solution}
    \begin{example}
        Example content here.
    \end{example}
    \begin{solution}
        Solution content here.
    \end{solution}
    \begin{solution}
        Solution content here.
    \end{solution}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


I wanted to extend my heartfelt thanks for the assistance you provided with my Beamer presentation. Your solution to the custom numbering for the example and solution environments was exactly what I needed to achieve the desired outcome.
After implementing the code you suggested, I was able to successfully apply the correct numbering scheme to my slides. The clarity and precision of your guidance made the process straightforward and efficient.
Your expertise and willingness to help are greatly appreciated.
Once again, thank you for your valuable help.

@WuGuiping You're welcome! Have fun with beamer!
